# Take screenshot in webcam using VFrames in Console Application

Tags: delphi

I'm doing a program to take a picture of the webcam using Delphi XE2 and VFrames to achieve this, the problem is that I have it all figured out, in a graphic application everything works fine, but when I use the unit in a console application, it returns me error saying

> First chance exception at $76B6B727. Exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 004A271B in module 'console.exe'. Read of address 00000260'. Process console.exe (3676)

My Unit :

```
unit Webcam;

interface

uses SysUtils, Windows, Vcl.Imaging.Jpeg, Vcl.Graphics, VSample,
  VFrames, Classes;

type
  TWebcam = class
  private
    procedure NewVideoFrameEvent(Sender: TObject; Width, Height: integer;
      DataPtr: pointer);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure capture_webcam(take_name: string);

  end;

var
  web_image: TVideoImage;
  name_screen: string;

implementation

constructor TWebcam.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
end;

destructor TWebcam.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

Procedure TWebcam.NewVideoFrameEvent(Sender: TObject; Width, Height: integer;
  DataPtr: pointer);
var
  bitmap: TBitmap;
  name: string;
begin
  name := name_screen;
  if (FileExists(name)) then
  begin
    DeleteFile(Pchar(name));
  end;
  bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
  web_image.GetBitmap(bitmap);
  bitmap.SaveToFile(name);
  bitmap.Free;
  web_image.VideoStop;
  web_image.Free;
end;

procedure TWebcam.capture_webcam(take_name: string);
var
  list_cams: TStringList;
begin

  web_image := TVideoImage.Create();

  list_cams := TStringList.Create;

  web_image.GetListOfDevices(list_cams);
  if not(list_cams.count = 0) then
  begin
    name_screen := take_name;
    web_image.VideoStart(list_cams[0]);
  end;

  list_cams.Free;

  web_image.OnNewVideoFrame := NewVideoFrameEvent;

end;

end.
```

Console :

```
program console;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Webcam;

var
  webcamz: TWebcam;

begin
  try
    webcamz := TWebcam.Create();
    webcamz.capture_webcam('test.jpg');
    webcamz.Free();
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code. What line specifically raises the exception?

Comment: Just in : web_image.VideoStart(list_cams[0]);

Comment: So what is `list_cams[0]` at that point? Is `web_image` valid (not nil)? We don't have your exact setup where we're sitting, so we can't step through the code and examine variables to narrow it down for you. You'll need to do that part. Set a breakpoint at that line of code and run to the breakpoint. Then examine the variables to see what their values are. The `00000260` address means that you're most likely accessing an object property of an object that is nil, and you only have a couple of objects in that line. Which one is invalid?

Comment: try showing with WriteLine () the content of "list cams [0]" and correctly displays the name of the webcam

Comment: Well, you checked exactly **half** of what I asked you to check. Now the other half: Is `web_image` valid (not nil)? I shouldn't have to fight to get details from you, and I shouldn't have to repeat requests for those details. Read what I wrote in my last comment again, please.

Comment: yes , web_image is valid , not nil , i change list_cams[0] for 'USB2.0 Camera' and follows the same mistake

Comment: the same code works well with forms

Comment: So did you step into `Video_Start` to see what happens there? Working in forms doesn't mean it will work from a console app. Forms have window handles and GUI elements. Console applications do not.

Answer (score 2):

The relevent source code for the `VFrames` unit is available on Github:

https://github.com/heise/GRBLize/blob/edge/VFrames.pas

https://github.com/heise/GRBLize/blob/edge/VSample.pas

The `TVideoImage.VideoStart()` method has a dependancy on `Application.MainForm.Handle`.  A console application does not have a `MainForm` by default, so that alone will crash the code in a console application unless you create a `MainForm` (which defeats the purpose of making a console app).

Aside from that, `TVideoImage` also has a dependancy on a message loop, as it creates a hidden window to receive video notifications used to fire the `OnNewVideoFrame` event.  Your console application does not have a message loop.  And even if it did, you are freeing the `TVideoImage` object before the event would fire anyway, as your `capture_webcam()` code is not waiting for the event to fire before exiting.

Also, `TVideoSample` class (which `TVideoImage` uses internally) uses the DirectShow API to capture images from the webcam's video stream. DirectShow is a COM-based API. Your console application is not initializing COM before using `TVideoImage`. That alone would cause `GetListOfDevices()` to fail and return a blank list. And if you attempted to ignore that and provide a device name anyway, `VideoStart()` would still crash when it tries to access a COM object that `TVideoSample` was not able to create during construction.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, then I can not do in console?

Comment: Not unless you alter the `VFrames.pas` source code to remove the `Application.MainForm` dependency, or else create a `MainForm` for your app.  Everything else I mentioned are issues in your own code outside of `TVideoImage`, so just fix those issues.